# How to navigate back to the last Nth cursor position in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code and wanted to know if we can set how much cursor history can VS Code save?

My common case scenario is as follow:

1) While reading through code, go to particular function definition using F12.
2) Read the entire function and come back to the original location from where the particular function is called( using ALT+ <-).

Now because I have read the entire function, if I do ALT+<--, it just navigates to the earlier line and that too only a few numbers of times.

So my question is can we set how many steps we can go back? Setting this number to a large value will help in this use case. Thanks.